# HTML force table row to be in column

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

In my HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>product 1</td><td>image 1</td></tr>
     <tr><td>product 2</td><td>image 2</td></tr>
</table>
```

would look like

```
+-----------+-------+
|  product 1|image 1|
+-----------+-------+
|  product 2|image 2|
+-----------+-------+
```

how do i make it look like:

```
+----------+---------+
| product 1|product 2|
+----------+---------+
| image1   |image 2  |
+----------+---------+
```

**Without changing the HTML, how can i solve this?**

jQuery, CSS, anything would be okay except modifying HTML!

I know this is not how table is used, but I need to change a table that is generated by the PHP and I can't touch the PHP (in this case)

Comment: are you against modifying the html via javascript?

Comment: no, but modifications to the table only :)

Comment: -1, Vague question with poor description of what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not the most compact solution, but this should work:

```
// map cells to 2D array
var cells = [];
$("tr").each(function(i,e) {
    cells.push($(e).find("td"));
});

// switch cell content of (0,1) and (1,0)
var cell1 = $(cells[0][1]);
var cell2 = $(cells[1][0]);
var temp = cell1.html();
cell1.html(cell2.html());
cell2.html(temp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ugly way to do it but working up to infinite length of row col:

http://jsfiddle.net/TXwq2/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way with a sort also

```
var f = $('td:contains(product)');
var d = $('td:contains(image)');
f.sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).text().replace('product', '') - $(b).text().replace('product', '');
});
d.sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).text().replace('image', '') - $(b).text().replace('image', '');
});
$('table > tbody').empty().append(f).children('td').wrapAll('<tr>');
$('table > tbody').append(d).children('td').wrapAll('<tr>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PFaVT/2/

Answer (score 0):

Not really elegant but should work [jsFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/47TTY/)

```
var newTableRow=[];
var newTableRow2=[];
$('table tr').each(function(){
    newTableRow.push($(this).find('td:first'))
    newTableRow2.push($(this).find('td:eq(1)'))
    });

$('table tr:first').append(newTableRow)
$('table tr:eq(1)').append(newTableRow2)​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
table tr:first-child > td:nth-child(2){display:inline; position:relative; left:-64px; top:24px}
table tr:last-child > td:nth-child(1){display:inline; position:relative; left:64px; top:-24px}
</style>
<table>
    <tr><td>product 1</td><td>image 1</td></tr>
     <tr><td>product 2</td><td>image 2</td></tr>
</table>
```

Hacktastic enough for you?